# One-to-One relationship not returning nested serializer in json response

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm trying to implement a one-to-one relationship between user and profile models so I can retrieve my profile with some nested user data.

This are my models:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username_validator = CustomUnicodeUsernameValidator
    username = models.CharField(
        _('username'),
        max_length=20,
        unique=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 15 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.'),
        validators=[username_validator],
        error_messages={
            'unique': _("A user with that username already exists."),
        },
    )
    email = models.EmailField(
        _('email address'),
        unique=True,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        error_messages={
            'unique': _("A user with that email already exists."),
        },
    )
    password = models.CharField(
        _('password'),
        max_length=128,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
    )

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        primary_key=True,
        parent_link=True,
        # related_name='usuario',
        # related_query_name='usuarios',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    bio = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )

    birth_date = models.DateField(
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )

    avatar_url = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )

    cover_url = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )


def create_profile_post_save(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        profile = Profile(user=instance)
        profile.save()


post_save.connect(create_profile_post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

serializers:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    full_name = serializers.CharField(
        source='get_full_name',
        read_only=True
    )

    password = serializers.CharField(
        min_length=8,
        required=True,
        allow_null=False,
        allow_blank=False,
        write_only=True,
        error_messages={
            'allow_null': 'Password cannot be null.',
            'blank': 'Password cannot be empty.',
            'min_length': 'Password too short.',
        },
    )

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = (
            'email',
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'full_name',
            'password'
        )
        extra_kwargs = {
            'first_name': {'write_only': True},
            'last_name': {'write_only': True},
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """Create and return a new user."""

        user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(
            username=validated_data.pop('username'),
            email=validated_data.pop('email'),
            password=validated_data.pop('password'),
            **validated_data
        )
        return user

class ProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [
            'url',
            'bio',
            'birth_date',
            'avatar_url',
            'cover_url',
            'user'
        ]
```

I'm trying to get a response like the following when sending a GET request to `http://localhost:8000/profiles/1/` :

```
{
    "user": {
      "url": "http://localhost:8000/users/1/",
      "email": "cthulhu@gmail.com",
      "username": "cthulhu",
      "fullName": "Marcos Rios"
    },
    "url": "http://localhost:8000/v1/profiles/1/",
    "avatarUrl": "assets/images/avatars/rick.jpeg",
    "bio": "Hincha de River Plate!",
    "birthDate": "1991-02-05",
    "coverUrl": "assets/images/monumental.jpg"
}
```

But instead, I'm getting a response without the user data. Something like this:

```
{
    "url": "http://localhost:8000/v1/profiles/1/",
    "avatarUrl": "assets/images/avatars/rick.jpeg",
    "bio": "Hincha de River Plate!",
    "birthDate": "1991-02-05",
    "coverUrl": "assets/images/monumental.jpg"
}
```

It's only returning the profile model information from the profile view. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to serialize the **`Profile`** instance, so you should have use **`user`** instead of **`profile`**

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        depth = 1
        fields = ['url', 'avatar_url', 'bio', 'birth_date', 'cover_url', 'user']
```

**Note**: This isn't a ***reverse relationship***

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, but I'm getting the same response (without user data)